# Apache is forcing https for subdomain

Tags: ssl, virtualhost, subdomain

I have a VPS with ubuntu 16, apache and the following three domains:

domain1.com
domain2.com

domain1 has SSL enabled. domain2 has no SSL. This is working fine. 
Now, I tried to create a new site using a subdomain of domain2:

portal.domain2.com

Whenever I try to open that site, the browser will show me a SSL error saying that my SSL certificate is not for that domain.
*But I don't want SSL on that domain/subdomain !*

My domain2.com.conf is identical with my portal.domain2.com.conf file, except for the ServerName and ServerAlias.

What could I be doing wrong?

domain1 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain2.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

portal.domain1 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@email.com
    ServerName portal.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/portal.domain2.com/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit 1:
If I run apachectl -tD DUMP_VHOSTS:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com-le-ssl.conf:2)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server 158.69.192.185 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost 158.69.192.185 (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain2.conf:1)
             alias www.domain2.com
     port 80 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/domain1.com.conf:1)
             alias www.domain1.com
     port 80 namevhost portal.domain2.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/portal.domain2.com.conf:1)
```

Comment: You could be doing wrong your configuration, which you haven't provided, though.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I edited my question with both configurations of domain 2

Comment: (1) You restarted apache after changing the config right? (2) what does `apachectl -tD DUMP_VHOSTS` show?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I edited the question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sending, or have you ever sent, a HSTS header with `includeSubDomains`?

Comment: @ShannonBlank it is the first time I hear about that. I should send that header as a client?

Comment: @Perroloco good god no, not unless you know what it does and what the implications are. If you _had_ sent that header in the past, it would explain the unexpected redirection, that's all

Comment: @ShannonBlank I just flushed the DNS and opened the url with different browsers. They all give me the same SSL error. I don't understand your comment :S

Comment: @Perroloco Don't worry. If you don't understand what HSTS does, then you won't understand what I was getting at.

Comment: I would have helped to give the true names for better diagnostics.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop default SSL response on Shared IP using SNI](https://serverfault.com/questions/510812/stop-default-ssl-response-on-shared-ip-using-sni)